# Как можно реализовать решение подобной задачи на python?

Tags: python

Имеется набор данных, состоящий из пар положительных целых чисел. Необходимо выбрать из каждой пары ровно одно число так, чтобы сумма всех выбранных чисел не делилась на 3 и при этом была максимально возможной. Гарантируется, что искомую сумму получить можно. Программа должна напечатать одно число — максимально возможную сумму, соответствующую условиям задачи.

Входные данные.

[Файл A](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/doc/inf/zadanie27/27-A_demo.txt)
[Файл B](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/doc/inf/zadanie27/27-B_demo.txt)

Даны два входных файла (файл A и файл B), каждый из которых содержит в первой строке количество пар N (1 ≤ N ≤ 100000). Каждая из следующих N строк содержит два натуральных числа, не превышающих 10 000.

Пример организации исходных данных во входном файле:

```
6
1 3
5 12
6 9
5 4
3 3
1 1
```

Для указанных входных данных значением искомой суммы должно быть число 32.

**В ответе укажите два числа:** сначала значение искомой суммы для файла А, затем для файла B.

**Предупреждение:** для обработки файла B не следует использовать переборный алгоритм, вычисляющий сумму для всех возможных вариантов, поскольку написанная по такому алгоритму программа будет выполняться слишком долго.

Comment: Можно попробовать отсортировать пары по **разности** между числами в них, потом взять максимальные числа во всех парах, чтобы получить максимальную сумму и затем начать перебирать варианты, стартовав от этой максимальной суммы и меняя пары начиная с пары с минимальной разницей и углубляясь дальше по мере надобности, пока не будет удовлетворено условие. Я могу и программу набросать, но судя по всему это учебное задание, смысл учебного задания в том, чтобы бы сами попытались его решить, а не кто-то сделал всё за вас.

Comment: Вернее, даже не числа в парах надо менять, а вот эту разницу между парами пробовать вычитать, начиная от минимальной. Сначала пробовать пару с минимальной разницей, потом брать цикл по двум парам с минимальной разницей и по ним перебор делать, потом по трём и т.д.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 4):

Нужно считать просто максимальную сумму (1) и в этом же цикле найти пару  с минимальной разницей неделящейся на три(2). Если конечная сумма (1) делится на три, просто вычти найденную разницу (2). И получишь ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для обоих файлов:

```
with open('27-A_demo.txt') as f:
    N = int( f.readline() )
    s, dMin  = 0, 10001
    for i in range(N):
        a, b = map( int, f.readline().split() )
        s += max( a, b )
        d = abs( a-b )
        if d % 3 > 0:
            dMin = min( d, dMin )
    if s % 3 != 0:
        print( s )
    else:
        print( s-dMin )
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, с чтением/записью из/в файл(а) разберетесь сами:

```
def find_max_sum(pairs):
    max_sum = 0
    min_diff = None
    for pair in pairs:
        max_sum += max(pair)
        diff = abs(pair[1]-pair[0])
        if (diff%3) and ((min_diff is None) or (diff < min_diff)):
            min_diff = diff
    if max_sum%3:
        return max_sum
    if min_diff is not None:
        return max_sum-min_diff
    return -1
```

Пример использования:

```
pairs = [
    [1, 3],
    [5, 12],
    [6, 9],
    [5, 4],
    [3, 3],
    [1, 1],
]
print(find_max_sum(pairs))
```

Comment: я немного изменил данные и мне выдало 33, хотя по  условиям 33 не может быть верным решением

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, исправил код. Думаю, теперь должен работать нормально.